# Perl one-liner to manipulate include directory

Tags: regex, perl

I have several hundred files with include directives that need to be changed.

The prototype is `#include "MyFile.hpp"`, but I need to append a directory in front of every include file like this: `#include "project-head/MyFile.hpp"`.

I've written a one-line perl script as follows:

`perl -p -i -e 's|/(#include /")/(.*/.hpp)|/1project-head/2|g' test_file.hpp`

But the test file doesn't seem to be changing. What is wrong with my with my `perl` expression?

Comment: Do you intend to use forward slashes? Looks like some ought to be excluded and others ought to be backslashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple odd slashes in your Perl script. The backrefs should be `\1`, `\2` etc and many of the rest should be dropped entirely.

```
perl -p -i -e 's|(#include ")(.*\.hpp)|\1project-head/\2|g' test_file.hpp
```

In case it's not blindingly obvious, `/` and `\` are two different characters with radically different semantics.

The prototype for the substitution command is `s/from/to/` but you can use, and have in your code used, different delimiters, so it's `s|from|to|` with no slashes at all (the only remaining forward slash is the directory separator between `project-head` and the original file name).

The backslash is commonly used as an escape character; for example, `\.` matches a literal period (whereas an unescaped `.` is a regex metacharacter which matches any character except newline).  It also has a special meaning in `\1` to refer back to the text matched by the first parenthesized subexpression (though in the replacement part `$1` is preferred).

Comment: Much better explained than I did; I've deleted my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. I will accept this in 43 seconds.